# Freeze after ~2mins of boot due to Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, freeze

I know this question has been asked a lot but it seems none of the proposed solutions work for my config.

**Configuration:** Ubuntu 20.04 (`5.11.0-38-generic`) and Nvidia RTX 3050, and dual booted with Windows 10.

I goto Software & Updates > Additional Drivers and enable Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested).

I then correctly enroll the MOK during the driver setup.

After few minutes from a reboot, my screen freezes, keyboard and mouse input does not work. I need to do a hard reboot.
I then quickly switch back to the Nouveau server to prevent the freeze.

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Overheating is most likely caused by dust. Power down your system. Unblock your fans and vents, clean out the dust. Ensure air circulation. Dust that coats heat exchangers and chips is a good insulator,  and bad for cooling. Don't disassemble your computer until you have downloaded the manufacturer's  manual, and researched how-to-clean. Make this information available for when your computer isn't (paper, other computer) **Don't use water.**

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I am sure this is not a overheating/dust issue because this is a very new laptop with nothing running on it. Regardless I'll try to read the logs.

Comment: Please also suggest what specific data I should look for in the logs, thanks